# Fusion Freeswitch Maximum Calls In Progress

Tags: postgresql, sip, pjsip, freeswitch, fusionpbx

I use Fusion core Freeswitch to build my PBX Server.

My version:
`FreeSWITCH version: 1.10.2-release-14-f7bdd3845a~64bit (-release-14-f7bdd3845a 64bit)`

it working find till last month BUT when user registrations reach to 1000
i have check Freeswitch log ( debug level) freeswitch still working
I have check postgreSql log still working

But client disconnected ( webrct from Web using SipJS and Zoiper use TCP protocol) and can not connect to Freeswitch for Registrations , so it can make any call at this time.
At this time when i see log it show "Maximum Calls In Progress"

I have try increase session reach to 5000 and session per second to 1000 and flush cached/ restart freeswitch but still not woking.

Here my [switch.conf.xml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N-gO70ZpfKO41Ulro_xZUPeYS7dUWiwn/view?usp=sharing)

Here my  [postgresql.conf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19JDMdpjXT68YgmWTyvvqXXGjfuh_MVml/view?usp=sharing)

Here my log when server down: [fs_log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_L2rbQDVgWPoN_VTEcT7ROHb3n4t6D0T/view?usp=sharing)
You can see i restart freeswitch at this log:

`2020-07-29 14:39:08.291394 [INFO] switch_core.c:2879 Shutting down ca289c03-0617-46bf-a7af-eda4a4fe2fbb 2020-07-29 14:39:08.291394 [NOTICE] switch_core_session.c:407 Hangup sofia/internal/1100365@125.212.xxx.xxx [CS_NEW] [SYSTEM_SHUTDOWN]`

Please take a look at help me solve this.

Comment: When you run `fs_cli -x 'status'` during that problem, what it shows? Can you post it here?

Comment: Here the status @os11k:  *UP 0 years, 0 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes, 9 seconds, 628 milliseconds, 247 microseconds
FreeSWITCH (Version 1.10.2 -release-14-f7bdd3845a 64bit) is ready
2 session(s) since startup
2 session(s) - peak 2, last 5min 2 
1 session(s) per Sec out of max 50000, peak 1, last 5min 1 
100000 session(s) max
min idle cpu 0.00/98.27
Current Stack Size/Max 240K/8192K*

Comment: can you show status during a problem, i see freeswitch is up only 9 seconds, so it seems you restarted it and only then printed out status.

Comment: this exactly when i get error: "UP 0 years, 0 days, 0 hours, 7 minutes, 52 seconds, 373 milliseconds, 218 microseconds
FreeSWITCH (Version 1.10.2 -release-14-f7bdd3845a 64bit) is ready
11 session(s) since startup
1 session(s) - peak 4, last 5min 1 
0 session(s) per Sec out of max 50000, peak 2, last 5min 0 
100000 session(s) max
min idle cpu 0.00/99.30
Current Stack Size/Max 240K/8192K"

Comment: this is strange, Freeswitch says "Maximum Calls In Progress", but it is not based on status. It is hard to say what is wrong without getting access to system, sorry

Comment: i see this lock maybe because it lock channels table but i dont know why: "Jul 30 22:05:57-freeswitch-1 freeswitch[103089]: 2020-07-30 22:05:57.334486 [ERR] switch_core_sqldb.c:1347 ERR: [select * from channels where hostname='-freeswitch-1.svr.omicrm.services' order by created_epoch]#012[ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block#012]"

Comment: I have try to config odbcinst.ini  set Threading = 0
for purpose driver postgres not lock but still no luck